# VS Server Explorer - column does not appear in the Columns list?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, sql-server-ce, server-explorer

For an existing table in SQL compact 4 db

Added a column of Type Bit, click OK 
but it does not show up in DataEditor nor in the list of columns
But it's there in the Table Schema editor

I am able to edit the data using ErikJ's SQL compact toolbox but curious about what rules i may have violated here  to cause this behavior ???

FYI - the column name is IsSys which is not shown, i added other bit columns for test and they appear in the columns list !

UPDATE - sql is below, IsSys and IsSystem both don't show up in Server Explorer list of columns or in ServerExplorer's DataEditor, though they show up in Table Schema Editor

```
CREATE TABLE [ProblemTable] (
  [AttrId] int NOT NULL  IDENTITY (30,1)
, [AttrTypeId] int NOT NULL
, [SelText] nvarchar(50) NOT NULL
, [SeqNum] int NOT NULL DEFAULT 9999
, [UpdatedBy] int NOT NULL DEFAULT 1
, [UpdatedAt] datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT getdate()
, [AttrKey] nvarchar(40) NOT NULL
, [IsEnabled] bit NOT NULL DEFAULT 1
, [IsShown] bit NOT NULL DEFAULT 1
, [IsSys] bit NULL DEFAULT 0
, [IsSystem] bit NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
);
GO
```

Comment: Please post a CREATE TABLE script so we can help you

Comment: @ErikEJ  the column was added via Server Explorer, that's where it doesn't show up ! added stmt above !

Comment: Use Chrome, translate to English: http://panicoenlaxbox.blogspot.com.au/2011/07/issys-en-sql-server-compact-40-es.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting - This appears to be "by design" - likewise table names starting with __Sys are filtered out. As stated in the article in spanish linked above, do not use IsSys for column names!

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation! i now know i'm not imagining things :) i appear to be on a roll here considering i have half a dozen other features/bugs that i hit with the control vendor on this project ! oh well !